# Find :$W_1 \cap (W_2 +W_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

let $W_1, W_2$ and $W_3$ be subspaces of $V$

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and 
$$W_1=\{(x,y)\in V:x=y\}$$ $$W_2=\{(x,y)\in V:x=0\}$$ $$W_3=\{(x,y)\in V: y=0\}$$

Then $W_1 \cap (W_2 +W_3)$ is  equal ______?

My attempt:
$W_1 \cap (W_2 +W_3)= (x,x) \cap \{(x,0) +(0,y)\}=(x,x) \cap(x,y) =(x,x)$

Is it correct?

Any hints/solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the heuristic is good. 
You only have to prove that $W_2+W_3=\Bbb R^2$, then $W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)=W_1$ immediately follows.